# How to include "Useless parentheses" rule in PMD

Tags: pmd

I found so many reference to exclude "Useless parentheses" from PMD. But I want to include this rule. My problem is, instead of having multiple useless parentheses and run pmd, I am not getting any PMD error. Please tell me how to enable this rule so that i can get PMD error - "Useless Parentheses".

In my ruleset.xml, It is written

Here is my ruleset.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="Custom ruleset"
         xmlns="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0 http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset_2_0_0.xsd">


    <description>
        NOTE !!!!  NOTE !!!!NOTE !!!!NOTE !!!!NOTE !!!!
        This list should be somewhat static. I have disabled most of the annoying checks.
        That said if we need to exclude rules we can.
        If there are specific instances we can use suppressions like:
        @SuppressWarnings("PMD.UseUtilityClass")  //Doesn't make sense as this is main...
        if we need to, but for the most part I would like to avoid suppressing and ignoring.
        If you do suppress, provide a note why.
        NOTE !!!!NOTE !!!!NOTE !!!!NOTE !!!!NOTE !!!!NOTE !!!!
    </description>

    <rule ref="rulesets/java/basic.xml"/>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/braces.xml"/>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/clone.xml"/>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/codesize.xml"/>
    <!--<rule ref="rulesets/java/comments.xml"/>-->
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/coupling.xml">
        <exclude name="LawOfDemeter"/>
        <exclude name="LoosePackageCoupling"/>
    </rule>

    <rule ref="rulesets/java/design.xml">
        <exclude name="ConfusingTernary"/>
        <exclude name="UseLocaleWithCaseConversions"/>
    </rule>

    <rule ref="rulesets/java/empty.xml"/>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/finalizers.xml"/>
    <!--<rule ref="rulesets/java/imports.xml"/>-->
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/javabeans.xml">
        <exclude name="BeanMembersShouldSerialize"/>
    </rule>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/junit.xml"/>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/logging-java.xml">
        <exclude name="GuardLogStatementJavaUtil"/>  <!--This rule assumes that we are using Log4J where a guard is needed
                                             but we are using slf4j where the guard isn't needed hence this is excluded  -->
    </rule>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/optimizations.xml">
        <exclude name="LocalVariableCouldBeFinal"/>
        <exclude name="MethodArgumentCouldBeFinal"/>
        <exclude name="AvoidInstantiatingObjectsInLoops"/>
    </rule>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/strictexception.xml"/>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/strings.xml"/>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/sunsecure.xml"/>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/unnecessary.xml"/>
    <!--<rule ref="rulesets/java/unusedcode.xml"/>-->

</ruleset>
```

Comment: Please, include the contents of your ruleset.xml, along with how you are using PMD to make sure PMD is actually taking your ruleset into account.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the docs, you can see that the rule you are interested in is part of the controversial ruleset: https://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.7.0/pmd-java/rules/java/controversial.html#UnnecessaryParentheses

In your ruleset you are not including any rule from this ruleset. You should therefore add it to your ruleset. You can either include the whole ruleset (not recommended) by adding `<rule ref="rulesets/java/controversial.xml"/>`, or just this one rule by adding `<rule ref="rulesets/java/controversial.xml/UnnecessaryParentheses"/>`